# how to use imap_open() for group in outlook 365

Tags: php, office365, imap

I'm having a big problem using `imap_open` to open the inbox of a 
group in Office 365.

All user folders are being listed in `imap_getmailboxes`, but the 
group does not pop up!

The group is already created as *SalaTeste1* that has the e-mail 
*salateste1@example.onmicrosoft.com*, but I can not access it using the 
same user password.

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$hostname = '{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}';
$username = "exemplo@exemp.onmicrosoft.com";
$password = 'exemplo@2018';

$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password, null, 1, 
array('DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR' => array('GSSAPI', 'NTLM','PLAIN'))) or 
die('Cannot connect to IMAP: ' . imap_last_error());

$list = imap_getmailboxes($inbox, "{$hostname}", "*");
if (is_array($list)) {
        foreach ($list as $key => $val) {
            echo "($key) ";
            echo imap_utf7_decode($val->name) . ",";
            echo "'" . $val->delimiter . "',";
            echo $val->attributes . "<br />\n";
        }
    } else {
        echo "imap_getmailboxes failed: " . imap_last_error() . "\n";
    }

    imap_close($inbox);


RESULT:

(0) {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate- 
cert}Anota��es,'/',64
(1) {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}Arquivo 
Morto,'/',64
(2) {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX,'/',68
(3) {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}Caixa de 
Sa�da,'/',64
(4) {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate- 
cert}Calend�rio,'/',32
(5) {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate- 
cert}Calend�rio/Anivers�rios,'/',64
(6) {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate- 
cert}Calend�rio/Feriados de Brasil,'/',64
(7) {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate- 
cert}Contatos,'/',32
(8) {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}Hist�rico de 
Conversa,'/',32
(9) {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}Itens 
Enviados,'/',64
(10) {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}Itens 
Exclu�dos,'/',32
(11) {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}Itens 
Exclu�dos/salaTeste1,'/',64
(12) {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate- 
cert}Journal,'/',64
(13) {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}Lixo 
Eletr�nico,'/',64
(14) {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate- 
cert}Rascunhos,'/',64
(15) {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate- 
cert}Tarefas,'/',64
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I was able to resolve this topic, it may close.